# ADuM140x: power only one side

Tags: digital-isolator

In my board it may happen to power only one side of the ADuM140x. All the pins on the other one will be completely floating. 
When the user plugs in a connector also the second side will be powered at 3.3V and the signals pins will be connected to the device too.

I cannot find in the datasheet is such a scenario is allowable.
Anyone has any experience on this?

Comment: And I wonder what is the state of the outputs in the powered side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [datasheet](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADuM1400_1401_1402.pdf):

> Unlike other optocoupler alternatives, the ADuM1400/ADuM1401/ADuM1402 isolators have a patented refresh feature that ensures dc correctness in the absence of input logic transitions and when power is not applied to one of the supplies.

[image]

Since you haven't provide a schematic (at this time) I can't comment as to what will happen in your case.